# Working with breeze, EF and oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, breeze

I am trying to create an application with Angularjs and breeze that talks to Oracle database.

Yes, my back end is oracle. And i found out that EF6 does not support oracle yet but EF5 does.

So i am trying to make breeze work with EF5. I installed EF5.

But i can find only breeze contextprovider for EF6. 
Is there not a breeze contextprovider for EF5? (I tried Breeze.Server.ContextProvider package but no result)

I am getting "Cannot resolve symbol EFContextPrvider"

Anybody faced same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I removed these from being viewed on Nuget because we are no longer supporting EF5 on an ongoing basis.  However, I have relisted the last released version of Breeze for EF5 and WebApi on Nuget, so you should be able to see them now. Please, note that newer versions of Breeze are all targeted at WebApi2 and the current documentation has mostly been converted to WebApi2 references as well.

Comment: Jay, can you pls give the names of the packages?

Comment: Breeze.WebApi ( for both client and server) or Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF for just the server. Note this is for Breeze.1.4.16 ( not the latest release, although it will probably work with the Breeze.1.4.17 client but not tested).

Comment: Thank you Jay. That fixed this problem. Please do not remove this :)

Comment: Jay, i am having trouble with these two packages [Breeze Server (Obsolete)-for legacy ASP.NET Web API (core) Version 1.4.16] and [Breeze Server (Obsolete)-for legacy ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework 5 Version 1.4.16]. When i build the solution, the packages are installed from Nuget but my csproj says the references to Breeze.WebApi, Breeze.WebApi.EF, Entity Framework, Newtonsoft.Json, System.Web.Http.OData and WebActivator are missing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I use breeze with EF5 (we can't update to 6 yet because we have a WCF RIA Services project that uses the same edmx files).

Download the breeze binaries from here:  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download

Inside the zip file look for the NetDlls folder.  The files named Breeze.ContextProvider.dll,  Breeze.ContextProvider.pdb, Breeze.WebApi2.dll and Breeze.WebApi2.pdb are what you are looking for.

I couldn't find a nuget package for the EF5 bits.